Drawing an outline around form fields
I am trying to figure out how to build the outline around the input field when the field is selected. See image below.

I tried inspecting the element, but I didn't find how the outline is added.
Can you help?
Thank you.

If you want to check the css related to hover, focus and others on an element when inspecting, just right click on the element in the inspecting window, and you can see in the emerging popup a "force state" section where you can then select "focus". The CSS rules will be shown then.

@AlvaroMenéndez Awesome. Thank you for the tip. It will be a huge help.

You can achieve this by playing on outline and outline-offset CSS properties of the inputs :


body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.input {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: none;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 1rem;
   border-radius: 1px;
}

.outlined {
   outline: 2px #fff solid;
   outline-offset: 2px;
}
<input type="text" class="input" />
<input type="text" class="input outlined" />



Please note that it will disable browser default outlining behavior.
